# respond to bluetooth headsets play/pause events

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've been able to respond to **wired** headphone events (play/pause) using `MPRemoteCommandCenter`, however this doesn't work for airpods.

Anything different I need to do to observe airpods or bluetooth headphones play/pause/button events? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, did you solve it?

Comment: @salty nope unfortunately :(

Comment: try to use "playCommand" and "pauseCommand" instead of "togglePlayPauseCommand"